# NavigationController.pushViewController crashes if run outside of mainQueue/mainThread

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code like this

```
SomeController *controller = [[SomeController alloc] init];
[self.navController setViewControllers:@[controller] animated:YES];
```

If run this code in `non-main thread`, then app crashes during `resignFirstResponder` of `viewController` which is executing the above code

If run this code in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{})`;

Then it works fine, **no crash**

Why does it crash in the **first case**? I thought if run in non-main thread, then UI wont see the changes but I did not expect it to crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to UIKit classes should take place on the main thread. Apple's [UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/) states:

> NOTE
>
> For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

Because UIKit assumes that it'll be running on the main thread, there are no real guarantees about what will happen if you try and access it on a different thread; your UI may not update, you may get a crash, etc. Some classes may even through an exception if they discover you're calling them on a non-main thread.

Comment: I suspect the UI code is mostly lockless for speed.  If you were able to call it from multiple threads, it would have to add locking which in the normal case would do nothing but slow things down.